# Font not displaying corrently in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

Our Wordpress theme is using the font montserrat which is displaying correctly in Chrome, IE and Safari but not in Firefox. Here is the styling:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratbold';
    src: url('./fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('./fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.svg#montserratbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratregular';
    src: url('./fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('./fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#montserratregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The website is accessible at http://www.poolerunners.org username: example password: example, it may ask you to type it twice.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Fonts are not loading in FF because of required authorization. You should check configuration of your web server.

[image]